# Convert nested join sql query to nested join LINQ

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, join

I am trying to convert nested join sql query to linq. I need some help to convert the query into linq. I am using vb.net.
This is my sql query:

```sql
SELECT tblJobSkillMatrix_JS.fldJobTitleID,
       tblRSCFMainLevel.fldRSCFMainLevel, 
       tblRSCFSkill.fldRCSFSkill, 
       tblSkillLevelDefinition.fldSkillLevelNum, 
       tblJobSkillMatrix_JS.fldPriorityJobSkill
FROM ((tblJobSkillMatrix_JS 
INNER JOIN (tblRSCFMainLevel 
      INNER JOIN tblRSCFSkill 
              ON tblRSCFMainLevel.fldRSCFMainLevelID = tblRSCFSkill.fldRSCFMainLevelID) 
      ON tblJobSkillMatrix_JS.fldRSCFSkillID = tblRSCFSkill.fldRSCFSkillID) 
INNER JOIN tblSkillLevelDefinition ON 
           tblJobSkillMatrix_JS.fldSkillLevelID = tblSkillLevelDefinition.fldSkillLevelID) 
INNER JOIN tblRSCFSkillGroupLevel ON
           (tblRSCFSkillGroupLevel.fldRSCFSkillGroupLevelID = tblRSCFSkill.fldRSCFSkillGroupLevelID) 
      AND  (tblRSCFMainLevel.fldRSCFMainLevelID = tblRSCFSkillGroupLevel.fldRSCFMainLevelID)
WHERE (tblJobSkillMatrix_JS.fldJobTitleID='F74F5BCA-F33A-4AE1-9825-16B05AB274F4') 
  AND (tblRSCFMainLevel.fldRSCFMainLevel='People skills')
ORDER BY tblJobSkillMatrix_JS.fldPriorityJobSkill;
```

Comment: Might be worth posting what you've tried so far, then someone could help you with the syntax etc.

Comment: I don't understand how to convert this query into LINQ.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: I am using telerik data access framework.

Comment: You certainly have checked the [telerik linq documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/linq-support/data-access-feature-ref-linq-support-querying-overview) haven´t you?

Comment: I already create many LINQ query using telerik data access framework. But this query is complicated I checked on the telerik documentation but I don't understand the way for nested join in a from clause.

Comment: you can use this tool for https://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx

Comment: this tool for creating the linq not converting the sql to linq.